# need to generate report by variable

Tags: ms-access

I have a database, as an example, I have an inventory table. Each record has an item id, item name, item category, etc.

I would like to be able to do things like generate all items with item code 1, but not write the report like that. I would like the user to be able to choose what category live. Is there a way to make a prompt?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create the report and have the recordsource prompt the user for the value... like below...

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.FldA, Table1.FldB
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.ID)=[Please enter desired Item Id for report]));
```

Or you could create a form with a comboBox to allow selection from a list, then run the report from there.

Comment: I apologize, but I haven't worked with Access much, I was sort of just pulled into this. How would one go about applying the sql above?

Comment: 1. Create your report (use report wizard if needed). This will ask you for the record source which can be a table or query. (2) Assuming you selected a table as record source, open the report in design view; (3) Click on the property value for Record Source; (4) click the build button (...); (5) Select all fields (or the ones needed for the report; (6) In the 'Criteria row for the field to filter on, enter [Enter ID for Report]   (7) Save the report and run it.